# Loop through folder and applying code to all xlsx

Tags: excel, vba

Had a code that was able to apply protect workbook but didn't save after running a different sub routine. I'm trying to apply a macro to all xlsx files in a folder where I'm deleting two sheets and applying a protect workbook. When I run it without the sheet deletion, the code runs but it doesn't apply to any of the files inside the folder.

```
Sub LoopThroughFilesFolder()
Dim StrFile As String, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
StrFile = Dir("C:\Users\user\Documents\Destroy\*.xlsx*")
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0

    For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Summary Copying" Or ws.Name = "Sum Totals" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    Next
    
    ProtectBookStructure ThisWorkbook, "password"
    StrFile = Dir
Loop
```

End Sub

Fixed with this code

```
 Sub LoopThroughFilesFolder()

   Dim myfile As String
   Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    myfile = Dir("C:\Users\user\Documents\Destroy\*.xlsx*")
    
        Do While myfile <> ""
           
           Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=myfile)
            
            For Each ws In Worksheets
            If ws.Name = "Summary Copying" Or ws.Name = "Sum Totals" Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
            Next
          
           ProtectBookStructure wb, "password"
           
        wb.Close savechanges:=True
        myfile = Dir
    Loop
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You question indicates to me that you are unfamiliar with the way to use workbooks. I'd suggest you to get started [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mx7a-uj2sZI) and if you're still stuck you can edit your question to explain what you've tried.

Comment: Just a little tip: If you find a solution you are not supposed to include it in the answer, you can actually post an answer to your own question. 
Also, I strongly recommend you get rid of the `ActiveWorkbook` reference in your solution by replacing the `Worksheets` with `wb.Worksheets` in the line `For Each ws In Worksheets`. Also, it is enough to use `"C:\Users\user\Documents\Destroy\*.xlsx"` (No trailing `*`!), unless you want your macro to get stuck on (hypothetical) files like `wb.xlsx.jpg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you check out the link posted by @DecimalTurn as a comment to your question.

A solution for your problem may look like this:

```vb
Sub LoopThroughFilesFolder()
    Dim strFile As String, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    strFile = Dir("C:\Users\user\Documents\Destroy\*.xlsx")
    
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        'Open the workbooks like this:
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(strFile, False, False)
        
        'In the following, use the "wb" variable to do what you want for the
        'opened workbook.
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            If ws.name = "Summary Copying" Or ws.name = "Sum Totals" Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.DELETE
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        Next
        ProtectBookStructure wb, "password"
        
        'Save and close
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

This code may still not work depending on how `ProtectBookStructure` looks like or if any of the workbooks in the folder are already password protected.

Comment: I had it working but testing it again with a new repopulated files in the folder, I get an error with both yours and my code "run-time 1004': Sorry, we couldn't find is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted? Any possible fix?

Comment: Which line does it fail on? I assume `Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(strFile, False, False)`? Look at the variable `strFile` in the watch window and check it the file it tries to open exists.

Comment: Yeah, fails on wb = application.workbooks.open. The variable is true when failing.

Comment: It shouldn't be `True`, it should be equal to some string (a file path)

Comment: Placing wb in the watch window I get the "filename.xlsx" . wb = nothing.

Comment: Hi @ojmayo. But what if you place just `strFile` in the watch window? It's a string variable, it can't be `Nothing`. I recommend you watch [this video](https://youtu.be/Um2JwZfwoFI "YouTube - Master VBA Debugging in 20 Minutes - Excel Macro Mastery (Paul Kelly)") on VBA debugging, I'm sure it'll help you a lot!